# Liberty 19.0.0.7 - How to load lpda profile attributes once logged in

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I'm currently running on WebSphere Liberty version 19.0.0.7 with ldapRegistry configured.   I am able to successfully login using the configured ldap, and I am interested in retrieving the full profile attributes for a logged in user.  My first thought was to use WIM client api, but I'm not 100% positive if that is a public api intended to be used for this purpose.  I'm also aware that I can retrieve the data via ldap directly and possibly through scim api.

In short, what is the correct api that I should be using to load the profile for the currently logged in user that utilizes the configuration already provided for my ldap registry?   With that knowledge, I can take the additional steps to research how to move forward.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jeff, you should use the SCIM API.

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan mentioned above, use the SCIM API.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_sec_scim.html

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_sec_scim_operations.html

The SCIM API requires configuring TLS as well as making the calls with a user who possesses either the reader or administrator role.